# How get href with a special src in child div in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy, selector

For getting all images of a site I write this code:

```
content = Selector(text = html)
all_images= content.css('img')
i = 0

for image in all_images:
    src =  image.css("::attr('src')").extract_first()
```

After getting the src of image, now I want to have the **href** of each image

```
<a href="/rayons/images" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'computer HP', 'htwe', 'ope_xxl_s22Englos');">
    <img src="/mySrc/" alt="something" class="ze-content">
</a>
```

How can I get **href** when I know the **Src** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do parent searches using **CSS**. In this case, **XPath** is a better fit. You could do this:

```
for image in all_images:
    src =  image.css("::attr('src')").extract_first()
    href = image.xpath('parent::a/@href').extract_first()
```

Or, using XPath's [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

```
href = image.xpath('../@href').extract_first()
```